# mac osx copy command for copying only files with a given subname?

Tags: macos

I want to copy (and overwrite) files and folders from a directory hierarch, only if they have a common string in name like 'fabrik'.

Example directory: `com_fabrik`, example file: `fabriklist.php`

Which terminal command should I use to execute this copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html)

```
find /your/directory -name="*.php" -exec cp -R {} ../otherfolder \;
```

Comment: thnx. Does this also copy/add directories with the subname? Also, I guess I need to use *.* instead *.php if want copy not only .php files...

Comment: Might want to use `cp -R` instead. It's corrected in the answer.

Comment: @Joppo And yes, you need to change the pattern inside `-name"=..."`